# How to remove all shadows, lights and gloss from render? 2.8

Tags: light, shadows

I do not have any camera nor lights yet whenever I switch from LookDev mode with textured models to Render preview it all suddenly gets darker and glossy. I've noticed that adding light to the scene actually reduces darkness according to position. Also in render workspace there are two spheres in right bottom corner where one is completely metallic, other is white but with shadows. How come the scene has these modifiers and how to completely remove them?

attached pic is what I'm talking about
[image: sad stuff here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't add any light to your scene, the **render** will be dark which only light up by environment light. (It will be weird when you can see object in a place with no light at all)

If you are not going to render it, use **DevLook** will be a better and easier way to look the scene with the power of EEVEE. You can also use **viewport render** if you want to get a screenshot.

And the little sphere is **preview light setting** overlay:
[image]

- left one: reflection map
- right one: diffuse map

If you want a shadowless and reflection less render:

Try to light up your scene by environment light
[image]

And also set the shader node if you want no **specular** at all:
[image]

Comment: so there is no way to: 1. get rid of reflections on final render? 2. set uniform light from ALL directions like in DevLook?

Comment: @JayJayAbrams Yes, that's done by environment light. Blender default use a dark but not black color for it. So you can see the objects in render view even though you didn't setup lights. I edit and update my answer

Comment: The reflection is a little bit complicated in CG. But the thing you want is the `Specular` value in Principle BSDF shader. Set it to `0` will give you a **flat** view of an object.

Comment: YES! Using diffuse BSDF instead of Principled was the solution here. Thank you!  While changing world color had no effect at all. Anyway , back in a days there was option for ray visibility https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZEqn.png is there anything similar today?

Comment: @JayJayAbrams Not in EEVEE but cycle. In the scene panel

Comment: could you please specify where exactly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ghyr.png Don't have any similar option. ps idk what I clicked but world color actually also started to work with no dependence to option "use nodes on/off"

Comment: @JayJayAbrams My bad, same in world panel. (You need to use cycles Render to see the option)